# Como executar uma função PHP em background?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Estou utilizando a API do cPanel para adicionar domínios estacionados dinamicamente. Até então tudo bem, envio os dados necessários  via `jQuery.post()` só que esse processo demora um pouco para ser concluído, cerca de 1 minuto.

Tem alguma alternativa para que o processo continue rodando em "segundo plano" e o usuário continue navegando pelo sistema?
Atualmente o usuário não consegue navegar até que o processo termine.

Comment: Você poderia tentar o uso de Threads(PHP) ou dar uma olhada nisso que talvez não seja o seu problema, mas é útil: http://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/

Comment: Podia abrir uma nova janela que dispara esse ajax e fica à espera. Senão podia fazer a navegação acontecer na mesma página, mudando só o conteudo de algumas partes da página.

Comment: Isto envolveria Messaging Pattern - SOA?

Comment: Valew galera abraço!

Comment: Poderia apenas gerar um agendamento pelo "cron".
Via PHP, crie um cronjob ou schtask (windows) e deixe programado para iniciar a tarefa em 1 minuto. Desse modo, o browser, a parte visual do usuário poderá navegar sem preocupação e sem precisar esperar pelo processo. Quanto ao agendamento rodando no server, quando completar, dispare um e-mail ao usuário ou mensagem, algo do tipo para avisar que completou. É apenas uma idéia.. Particularmente uso muito isso. Prefiro assim do que ações assíncronas ou o uso de ignore_user_abort().

Answer (score 4):

No próprio script PHP, acrescente no início as seguintes linhas:

```
set_time_limit( 7200 ); // Limite de tempo de execução: 2h. Deixe 0 (zero) para sem limite
ignore_user_abort( true ); // Não encerra o processamento em caso de perda de conexão
```

Abaixo dessas linhas programe normalmente.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

Creio que seja possível fazer a execução em background usando o cURL como no exemplo abaixo:

**background-script.php**

```
if ($_GET['iniciarbackground'] == 'true') { // chamada iniciada pelo ajax
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.yoursite.com/background-script.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);

    // repassar ao cURL, tudo que recebeu como POST:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
} else { // chamada iniciada pelo cURL
// tarefas a executar no background

}
```

**jquery:**

```
$.post( "background-script.php?iniciarbackground=true", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Fonte: http://www.paul-norman.co.uk/2009/06/asynchronous-curl-requests/

Comment: Muito obrigado Jader. realmente com cURL dá pra ser feito da forma que esperava. um abraço! tudo de bom.

Answer (score 0):

Penso que a melhor alternativa para você é criar um daemon em php, para isso você teria que ter um outro servidor(worker) que pode ser barato pois você pode gerenciar uma fila de forma cadenciada. Para realizar esse trabalho recomendo o uso de [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) é excelente, a documentação do PHP se encontra [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.gearman.php)

Comment: Interessante. Será que vc explicar melhor isso de que threads ainda não são estáveis? Qual problemas podem acontecer?

Comment: Acho melhor eu tirar esse comentário sobre threads pois não encontrei na documentação novamente, provavelmente vai depender da versão do seu PHP acredito que nas versões 5.5 para cima já é bem estável. Peço desculpas

Comment: Valeu Fábio. consegui resolver o problema com ajuda do Jader. Utilizando cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Deve haver algo errado, se não me engano o jQuery por padrão faz as requisições ajax sem "TRAVAR" a navegação, async.

De qualquer maneira verifique se as requisições estão sendo feitas de forma assicrona.

Para os usuários com host windows (aproveitando a pergunta) existe a função:

**win32_create_service** do PHP que permite rodar um script como serviço, com opções de parar, pausar, etc...